# Question about elementary property of Jacobi sums

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

Writing this up as a question seemed to clarify things, but I just want to make sure that I am understanding things correctly. Let $\mathbb{F}_{p} = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $\chi$ a nontrivial multiplicative character on $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, and $\chi^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $\chi$. I am trying to follow the proof that $J(\chi, \chi^{-1}) = -\chi(-1)$ from Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*. Now we have that $$ J(\chi, \chi^{-1}) = \sum_{a + b = 1} \chi(a) \chi^{-1}(b) = \sum_{\substack{a + b = 1\\b \neq 0 }} \chi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \sum_{a \neq 0} \chi \left( \frac{a}{1- a} \right).$$ Now if we set $a/(1 - a) = c$ and $c \neq -1$, then $a = c/(1 + c)$. Now comes the part of the proof that I was struggling with, they go on to say:

> It follows that as $a$ varies over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, less the element 1, that $c$ varies over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, less the element $-1$. Thus $$ J(\chi, \chi^{-1}) = \sum_{c \neq -1} \chi(c) = - \chi(-1).$$

Is this because $$ J(\chi, \chi^{-1}) = \sum_{a \neq 0} \chi\left(\frac{a}{1 -a} \right) = \sum_{c \neq -1}\chi(c) = - \chi(-1) + \sum_{c \in \mathbb{F}_{p}} \chi(c) = - \chi(-1)?$$

EDIT: Forgot the $-$ sign in the line $J(\chi, \chi^{-1}) = - \chi(-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it holds because of Proposition $8.1.2$ in Ireland-Rosen, namely that 
$$\sum _{t\in\mathbb{F}_p} \chi(t)=0, $$ for $\chi\neq \epsilon$.

Comment: But we aren't assuming that $\chi$ is the Legendre character. I have shown that $\sum_{a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}} \chi(a) = 0$ if $\chi$ is a nontrivial character though.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong page of Ireland-Rosen.

Comment: Okay great. I understood what you meant, but just wanted to be sure :).